# Search Core Results Custom Paging

Tags: search-results, paging

I have to implement a requirement to have custom paging on the Search Core Results web part.

I have tried to modify the web part XSL but cannot seem to get the properties to implement paging as they don't seem to be getting passed to the XSL.

Another route I was trying was to add the Search Paging web part but I couldn't find any way of customising it.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Can you please explain how you want to customize it?

Comment: I need to customise the look and feel to display [showing x to y of z] and next previous buttons without the page numbers.

Comment: You can change the look and feel through CSS. I'm not sure you are going to be happy with the capabilities for the other paging parts like showing x to y of z.  Search really doesn't know how many total items/pages there are.  It takes a guess and that guess changes as you page.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I could put in [showing x to y of about z]. I know I could change the look and feel through CSS but ideally I would like to get at the HTML is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use the Paging Web Part instead? This is how this is normally handled on the seaerch page.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg576964.aspx

Comment: How do you customise the look and feel of the paging web part?